# Boolean logic convert DNF to CNF

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I need to convert this DNF

`(!A && C && !D) || (!B && C && !D) || (A && B && !C) && (A && B && D)`

into CNF notation. The thing is, when using wolfram alpha, it shows me the correct answer, but when I try to solve it by parts, it doesn't work.

I've tried using the last part `A && B && D` to split the large sequence into three large parentheses but calculating them separately with wolfram alpha doesn't show the same results. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two disjunctions share `C && !D`,  The last expression can be simplified.

Use the distributive property for in the first; i'll exemplify the first use in this  case.

`(!A && C && !D) || (!B && C && !D) = (C && !D) && (!A || !B)`

In the second disjunct

`A && B` is redundant in the chain of conjunctions in the third disjunct of you original boolean formula.

`A && B && !C && A && B && D  = A && B && !C && D.`

So we have:

`(C &&  !D && (!A || !B)) || (A && B && !C && D)`

Now distribution is needed, again. (And again). But I've given you a good start.

Comment: @Traabefi  Yes, do what amWhy does! Keep distributing || over &&, and eventually it'll be in CNF